# Alarm only work when screen is ON

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My app use AlarmManager to schedule a task with a specific time. Almost worked well but on some devices, user feedback to me the alarm only fire when the screen on their phone is ON, if they turn of the screen, alarm did not fire. This issue happened on several Android OS version (4.4, 5.1, 6.0)
I researched but still can not find the cause of this issue.
Do any body have the same issue like me and what is your solution to fix ?

Below is the code I use to schedule task.

```
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, myTodo.getId(), alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
```

I use **WakefulBroadcastReceiver** to start a Service (not IntentService).

I found on some tutorial about AlarmManager, They used a attribute on manifest receiver:

```
android: process =":remote"
```

Does this attribute can fix this issue ?

Comment: No, that won't do anything.  It has to do with what thread the receiver runs on, it isn't needed (the tutorial was probably wrong to use it, but I can't be sure without knowing what else it does).

Comment: have you used Wakelogs to run task using alarm manager?

Comment: @Divyesh I used WakefulBroadcastReceiver, I think this already helped for WakeLock

Comment: i am using alarm for get notifiaction every day, and it is working even when screen is off

Comment: I don't think it is a code issue if it works on some device. Some devices come with built in battery manager app which might be killing the process when screen is off. If the devices have such apps you have to make your app protected in the settings. I had the similar problem and solved it by doing so. You can give it a try